# Does dart have an equivalent to C# discards?

Tags: dart

C# discards prevent allocation of values not needed. Is there something similar in dart? I saw a lot of people use the underscore as if it were a discard, but using two at the same time (like this `(_, _) => method()` will say the variable `_` is already defined.

Comment: Dart does not have those.  Some people use multiple underscores for additional variables to indicate that they are unused (e.g. `(_, __) => ...`).

Comment: Thanks for providing the common practice. Altough if there is no optimized implementation behind it, it doesn't really matter. On the other hand, the double underscore is a good idea, not bad

Answer (score 0):

Dart does allow you to use the same discard operator as C#. You can define a variable or final with a name of `_`. This works well with the rule `avoid-ignoring-return-values` ([Dart Code Metrics](https://dartcodemetrics.dev/)) Importantly, if you name the variable with this, you will not encounter the warning `unused-local-variable`. However, there is another code rule called `no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers`. You can safely turn this off as long as you don't have someone in your team that has a habit of prefixing variable names with an underscore.

Ignoring the return value
[image]

Discarding the return variable
[image]

Unfortunately, it doesn't work the same way as C# because it involves an assignment, and you cannot assign two different types to it. You need to declare it as an `Object?`
[image]

Comment: But in dart a leading underscore serves as the access modifier private. [Dart documentation 'libraries-and-visibility'](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility)